# Estimating CI using confint() for GLMM leads to error in zetafun (np,ns)

Tags: r, glm, lme4, confidence-interval

I have a GLMM with binary variables using R version 3.6.2 and lmerTEST 3.1-2 and I would like to get confidence intervals. So I've used `confint()` function.

Here:

```
model71<-glmer(fetale_Schwangerschaftskomplikationen~Infektion_in_Schwangerschaft+(1|Pat_ID),data=CED,family="binomial")
```

With the `summary()` function I get resulst without a warning, but for the confidence intervals I get:

```
confint(model71)
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
Error in zetafun(np, ns) : profiling detected new, lower deviance
```

I tried to solve the problem like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com), by boosting the `devtol` parameter using the `confint.merMod`.
But this boosting isn't working for me. Boosting `devtol` to 1e-8,1e-7 or 1e-6 does give me the same output:

```
confint(model71)
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
Error in zetafun(np, ns) : profiling detected new, lower deviance
```

Does anyone have another idea for me, how i can solve this problem?
(I am sorry for my bad English)
Thanks

Comment: With `confint.merMod`, you can choose your method. Try with `confint.merMod(object = your_model, method = your_method)`, replacing `your_method` with either "boot", "Wald", or "profile".

Comment: Thank you!  `method="profile"` leads to the same error, and the confidence intervals from "Wald" and "boot" differ a lot. So how can I get to the "real" confidence intervals?

Comment: Could you post some example data? I have a script that I use for linear mixed models that I think would work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your first hint! I talked to my tutor and he said, the 'method="Wald"' would be the best solution for my problem!

Answer (score 2):

As proposed in the commend, you can specify the method used for generating confidence intervals in with `confint.merMod()` with the `method` parameters, like `confint.merMod(model, method = "Wald")`.

Options include bootstrapping (`boot`), Wald (`Wald`), and profile (`profile`).
As always, your experimental setup will determing what suits your usecase the best.